# Does Azure support using Linux as the OS instead of Windows for PaaS Web Apps?

Tags: linux, windows, azure, web-applications

I'm trying to figure out through the interface as well as via the documentation and blog articles if Azure has a PaaS option that runs on top of Linux instead of Windows.

Comment: What exact PaaS are you looking for?

Comment: Why does it matter? Platform as a Service, by definition, doesn't care about the underlying host OS - the platform is provided to you as a service. You just bring your code.

Comment: Very true, and something I've spent time thinking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure now offers App Service (which hosts Web Apps) on Linux. Currently it's considered *Preview* and only available in a few regions, but... it's announced and available.

More information may be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-linux-intro/).

Answer (score 1):

If it's PaaS it's by nature abstracted away from the OS. Redis as a service, for example, can be had on Azure. Is it hosted on Linux? Hosted on Windows? It's not transparent. Who cares? It's Redis as a service and works one way or the other.

Comment: Are you sure this is for PaaS and not IaaS?

Comment: @Omega My mistake.

Comment: @Wesley Please be more constructive with your answer than just providing a single "Yes" link...

Comment: @krisFR Yes was the perfect answer... if it had been right. =)

Comment: Hardly, I would have asked that question either way. Try to assume someone has done a simple 2 word Google search.  Which is what it looks like you did here.  You didn't even have the link posted initially either, you edited it in!

Answer (score 1):

Presently, the answer from Microsoft/Azure is [*"not in the short term, but it could happen later"*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70f50c06-086b-4fab-a996-d2010b39c939/question-about-setting-up-a-paas-web-app-compatibility-with-linux).

---

As we are talking about PaaS, optimistically speaking and by design, the platform shouldn't be a consideration.  For many situations, this should be true, although there may be exceptions when functionality does split along OS lines.  The best example would be a native library integration on your platform of choice - of course this cuts both ways as there may be some libraries only available running on Windows as well.

The only remaining difference would be performance, but if that's an issue, then it stands to reason it should be raised as a support item.

---

The takeaway here is that there is a very strong case for selection so that people can choose the operating system that best suits their needs.

I've created the corresponding [feature request](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/8362119-support-linux-for-paas) which you should upvote if you're interested in seeing this happen.

If you're interested in advocating a bit further, you can also consider retweeting [this](https://twitter.com/Omega_/status/608957055664332800) to your friends and colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

All Web Apps run on top of Windows hosted by IIS or Apache. No exceptions.